# Streaming video to embedded VLC via ASP.Net - Unable to seek position

Tags: c#, asp.net, vlc

I am trying to write a video streaming site using an embedded VLC control to play the video and an asp.net handler to get the video stream. I am embedding the control as follows:

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" width="640" height="480" target="http://MyWebsite/MyHandler.ashx"/>
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab"></object>
```

And the code i am using in the handler to stream the video is:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Buffer = false;
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        var path = @"c:/file.avi";
        var file = new FileInfo(path);
        var len = (int)file.Length;
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", len.ToString());
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        var outStream = context.Response.OutputStream;
        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            int bytes;
            while (len > 0 && (bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                len -= bytes;
            }
        }
    }
```

While this works and streams the video, I am unable to seek back or forward, the seek bar doesn't move at all. I thought since I sent the file size it would be able to calculate positions but I guess not. Is it possible to seek in the video or will it not be possible since it is a stream (even though it is not a 'true' stream since it is coming from a file with a defined size etc)

Comment: I used your code to embed vlc plugin and hanlder to secure the links, but I am failed to play rtmp links. Can you plz help me how to play rtmp links via hanlder. [my question for you plz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826415/http-hanlder-for-string-return-asp-net)