# why java streaming video is not playing in crome browser but is playing in firefox

Tags: java, spring-mvc, video-streaming

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/video/{clientID}/{fileName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getClientVideo(@PathVariable(value = "clientID") Integer clientID, @PathVariable(value = "fileName") final String fileName) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    String absolutePath = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(Paths.get(absolutePath).getParent() + "/" + clientID);
    if (null != file) {
        FilenameFilter beginswithm = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File directory, String filename) {
                return filename.contains("ClientVideo_"+fileName);
            }
        };
        File[] files = file.listFiles(beginswithm);
        if (null != files && files.length > 0) {
            Resource resource = null;
            for (final File f : files) {
                headers.set("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + f.getName());

                StreamingResponseBody responseBody = new StreamingResponseBody() {
                    @Override
                    public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                        out.write(Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath()));
                        out.flush();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).body(responseBody); //(responseBody, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }
    }
    RecruiterResponseBean resBean = new RecruiterResponseBean();
    resBean.setStatusMessage("Video is not present : " + Constants.FAILED);
    resBean.setStatusCode(Constants.FAILED_CODE);
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

I am using Spring MVC, I tried many methods but all are downloading the video. Above code is streaming the video, the problem is: in firefox it is streaming but in crome it is downloading. I want to play streaming video in crome also like below ex.
[Ex streaming video: http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4]

Do I need to add more Headers? [if so, which headers need to add?]
Or Did i miss anything?

Comment: Try adding vlc extension to browser.If it works then problem would be more narrowed

Comment: Hi, Thank you for quick replay. [vlc extension link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-in-vlc-media-player/ihpiinojhnfhpdmmacgmpoonphhimkaj?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) I added above vlc extension to crome, but result is same. after adding, need to play directly in browser or where should i play streming link?

Comment: Please look here if you need to stream video and have its url.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635821/streaming-video-to-embedded-vlc-via-asp-net-unable-to-seek-position

Comment: streaming is very slow. how to increase the efficiency? i am using tomcat 7 and spring MVC